# set row number to various actions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, row-number

I'm trying to set row numbers to a table's output.

Table looks like

```
AccountNum  DataAction  ActionType  ActionStartCounter
123         11/01/2013  HELLO       1
123         12/01/2013  NONO        NULL
123         16/01/2013  YESYES      NULL
123         1/02/2013   HELLO       2
123         4/02/2013   YESYES      NULL
456         10/01/2013  HELLO       1
456         13/01/2013  NONO        NULL
456         14/01/1900  WHYWHY      NULL
456         15/01/2013  YESYES      NULL
456         20/03/2013  HELLO       2
456         31/03/2013  YESYES      NULL
```

What this is trying to do is

1) Every time there is Hello for an account it sequences the table based on DateAction under the column `ActionStartCounter`

2) the `NULLs` signify these actions are not HELLO and are part of Previous Numbered row

```
i.e. for AccountNum 123 NONO on 12/01/2013 is linked to HELLO on 11/01/2013.
```

3) YESYES is the last action for any Account for any start by HELLO.

I want the output to be

```
AccountNum  DataAction  ActionType  ActionStartCounter    ActionCounter
123         11/01/2013  HELLO       1                     11
123         12/01/2013  NONO        NULL                  12
123         16/01/2013  YESYES      NULL                  13
123         1/02/2013   HELLO       2                     21
123         4/02/2013   YESYES      NULL                  22
456         10/01/2013  HELLO       1                     11
456         13/01/2013  NONO        NULL                  12
456         14/01/1900  WHYWHY      NULL                  13
456         15/01/2013  YESYES      NULL                  14
456         20/03/2013  HELLO       2                     21
456         31/03/2013  YESYES      NULL                  22
```

Where new field ActionCounter will essentially be concatenation of

`ActionStartCounter` and rownumber within the `accountNum` and `ActionStartCounter`

meaning

the second piece in the concatenation is about the row_number within the start of the HELLO, as soon as new HELLO comes in the counter resets.

ActionStartCounter also is based on case when `ActionType ='Hello' then row_number()` over(partition by AccountNum order by DateAction)

If you guys reckon that should be changed we can get that done. If you think the AccountNum or Date can be part of the new column to make it unique we can do that. There is no limitation on number of fields we need to transform to get to last column.

Thanks for your help.

**PS:** Platform SQL Server 2005

Here's DDL

```
Create Table ActionDetails
(
AccountNum Int,
DataAction datetime,
ActionType Varchar(25),
ActionStart int 
)

Insert into ActionDetails
Select 123,CONVERT(datetime,'20130111' ,112),'HELLO',1 UNION 
Select 123,CONVERT(datetime,'20130112' ,112),'NONO',NULL UNION 
Select 123,CONVERT(datetime,'20130116' ,112),'YESYES',NULL UNION 
Select 123,CONVERT(datetime,'20130201' ,112),'HELLO',2 UNION 
Select 123,CONVERT(datetime,'20130204' ,112),'YESYES',NULL UNION 
Select 456,CONVERT(datetime,'20130110' ,112),'HELLO',1 UNION 
Select 456,CONVERT(datetime,'20130113' ,112),'NONO',NULL UNION 
Select 456,CONVERT(datetime,'20130114' ,112),'WHYWHY',NULL UNION 
Select 456,CONVERT(datetime,'20130115' ,112),'YESYES',NULL UNION 
Select 456,CONVERT(datetime,'20130320' ,112),'HELLO',2 UNION 
Select 456,CONVERT(datetime,'20130331' ,112),'YESYES',NULL
```

Comment: What do you expect ActionCounter to be after 19 or 29?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I want it to be 110. I think I can handle it in next set of DML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(456 doesn't start with `HELLO` - not sure how to handle).
Had to rewrite your dates, might have made an error there. The mechanics should be sound though.

```
;WITH MyTable (AccountNum,  DataAction,  ActionType,  ActionStartCounter) AS
(
SELECT 123,         CAST('01/11/2013' AS DATETIME),  'HELLO',       1       UNION ALL
SELECT 123,         '01/12/2013',  'NONO',        NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 123,         '01/16/2013',  'YESYES',      NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 123,         '2/1/2013',   'HELLO',       2      UNION ALL
SELECT 123,         '2/4/2013',   'YESYES',      NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 456,         '1/10/2013',  'HELLO',       1      UNION ALL
SELECT 456,         '1/13/2013',  'NONO',        NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 456,         '1/14/1900',  'WHYWHY',      NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 456,         '01/15/2013',  'YESYES',      NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 456,         '03/20/2013',  'HELLO',       2     UNION ALL
SELECT 456,         '3/31/2013',  'YESYES',      NULL   
)
,CTE AS
(
    SELECT   * 
            ,SeqGroupAcc    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNum ORDER BY DataAction)
    FROM MyTable
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT   *
            ,MyCounting = 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE SeqGroupAcc = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   T2.AccountNum
            ,T2.DataAction
            ,T2.ActionType
            ,CASE WHEN T2.ActionStartCounter IS NULL THEN T1.ActionStartCounter ELSE  T2.ActionStartCounter END
            ,T2.SeqGroupAcc
            ,CASE WHEN T2.ActionType = 'HELLO' THEN 1 ELSE T1.MyCounting + 1 END
    FROM CTE2   T1
    JOIN CTE    T2 ON T1.SeqGroupAcc = T2.SeqGroupAcc - 1 AND T1.AccountNum = T2.AccountNum
)                                                       
SELECT   AccountNum
        ,DataAction
        ,ActionType
        ,ActionStartCounter
        ,ActionCounter  = (ActionStartCounter) * 10 + MyCounting
--OR: ,ActionCounter    = CAST(ActionStartCounter AS VARCHAR(5)) + CAST(MyCounting AS VARCHAR(5))
FROM CTE2
WHERE AccountNum = 123
```

Comment: That works perfect for 123 . The 456 entry for 14/01/1900 was typo. If I redo your MyTable (apologies for no DDL- added that now) I get what I wnated. I'll test LievenKeersmaekers 's theory of more than 10 occurnaces. It is rarity. But hey - you never know what you dont know.

Comment: As you guys can imagine it is dummy data - let me test it on my actual data and get back to you.

Comment: I've added in an alternative expression for `ActionCounter` - whatever your requirements are, given `ActionStartCounter` and `MyCounting`, you should be able to express the desired `ActionCounter`.

Comment: That was almost what I was testing just then     `,ActionCounter1  = cast(ActionStartCounter as varchar)  + cast(MyCounting as varchar)`

Comment: That works very well on Dummy data. I'll apply it on my actual table and let you know. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/676c9/17) is essentially the same approach - there has to be a better way doesn't there?

Comment: Yes - there has to be better approach - I think Mark D's solution fits to what my requirements are - for now.